# How to combine multiple phrases when summarizing an article

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis, sentence-patterns

Let's say if I am summarizing an article that describes these things:

- How to slay a dragon (in 500 words)
- How to install Linux (in 500 words) and
- How to cook a scrambled egg (in 300 words)

I want to summarize what the article is about in a single sentence. I am confused on how to combine them the three major topics covered in the article. It would be great if someone could help me with it.

My Statements:

1. The article describes how to slay a dragon, how to install Linux and how to cook a scrambled egg.
2. The article describes how to slay a dragon, install Linux and cook a scrambled egg.

My the above statements which one is more appropriate? The first one or the second one? It would be great if you could point out the mistake(s) in either of them. If both are not correct, please suggest some other alternative.

Comment: In the first they are definitely independent. In the second it could be a sequence of actions. You would need the second if the dragon is guarding the Linux installation media and the egg is to be cooked on a computer-controlled stove.

Comment: ... the implication in @Peter's fine comment being that these, being very disparate topics,  are best reported in the non-sequence-implying style of your first version. It's more staccato, compartmentalising better.